# Communication between iOS and OSX

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I'm developing a medical record system for iOS and OSX. The idea is to have the iPad devices contain the presentation layer and just a tiny bit business layer, while the actual business layer is running on a Mac OSX machine.

I would really appreciate thoughts on which basic communication to use between the iPads and the OSX machine. Web services? Game kit? Remote objects? The actual data must be protected by SSL.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Remote Objects are not available on iOS.

Comment: You're right. I didn't see your comment until now, sorry.

Comment: Important to note that in this domain (medical records), a great many *very important* regulations exist that will dictate the levels and types of security you must have. Be very careful to make sure that you are at least aware of those regulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to write a web service and expose an XML API. Then, enforce SSL constraints on all resources and program your iOS device to use the standard HTTP verbs to communicate with the server. Depending on the web platform you select, a number of wrappers exist to help with the communication. For example:

[iPhone on Rails](http://iphoneonrails.com/)

Comment: Why not remote objects? The server side platform is OSX. I'm not arguing, I just want to know what the drawbacks of that strategy would be and why you'd choose web services.

Comment: Ok, I realize in the meanwhile that remote objects aren't available on iOS. I'll wait a bit longer to see if I get other tips before flagging the answer.